# search Google programmatically

Tags: search

Does anyone know if and how it is possible to search Google programmatically without entering the query in a search box? I want to double click a word in a webpage and get the google search results.

Answer (score 2):

You could just link to the URL:

`http://www.google.com/search?q=query+here`

Pretty simple. Also, if you use `.com` it *should* automatically redirect to the user's own language-specific page, unless you specify the language in the `lang=` parameter.

Comment: I have checked that. it generates  "permission denied" error.

Comment: Where? On Google? Or somewhere else?

Comment: actually the error is on this line: req.open('GET', url , false);

Comment: I meant you could just link the user to the search URL. If you want the results to be loaded into your code programmatically, use the custom search API as recommended by Tetaxa.

Comment: but just a question. when I run my application on localhost, it works properly. but when I want to run form my pc it generates the error. is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bookmark, AKA, a bookmarklet since its actually JavaScript code in most any web browser:

```
javascript:window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" +
encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection()).substr(0,2000), "_self");
```

you can substitute Google for Bing or any preferred search engine, e.g.,

```
javascript:window.open("http://www.exalead.com/search/web/results/?q=" +
encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection()).substr(0,2000), "_self");
```

will open up a query at Exalead, a European competitor to Google.

Breaking it down, the JavaScript code does the following

```
javascript:window.open( // we will be opening  a link
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + // we will be using Google as our base search engine
    encodeURIComponent( // we have to convert spaces to %20 and change rest of string to encoded URI specs
        window.getSelection()).substr(0,2000), // get the selected text and grab first 2000 characters of encoded string
    // since Google caps string queries at 2048 characters - you may have to shorten this slightly
    "_self"); // open in same tab - use "_blank" or other desired target
```

Comment: I have similar problem but i would like to enter the keywor programmatically in the search box and then hit the search button , even this programmatically but showing the user what is happening. How can i do it?